# Need to know how to use the spread operator for an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a reactJS application and would like to know if there was an easier way to assign my state object to the data being returned from a rest.  Perhaps using a spread operator?

```
state = {
        recordid: "",
        companyname: {val:"",err:""},
        address: {val:"",err:""},
        telephone: {val:[],err:""},
        email: {val:[],err:""},
        taxid: {val:"",err:""},
        weburl: {val:"",err:""},
        loading: true
    }
```

The data coming back from the server looks like this:

```
{
  "address": "9242 Kropf Court\nTulsa, OK 74133", 
  "balance": "1937.2400", 
  "companyname": "HUB Pharmaceuticals, LLC", 
  "email": [
    {
      "emailaddress": "lespinha4r@salon.com", 
      "emailname": "Lizbeth Espinha", 
      "recordid": "ea18a1b3-860d-45ed-a6bc-b5208dcfbac7"
    }
  ], 
  "recordid": "fe435915-0e5c-4165-80ca-28c69a5d1ed8", 
  "taxid": "132798707", 
  "telephone": [
    {
      "phonename": "Office", 
      "phonenumber": "9185499797", 
      "recorder": 1, 
      "recordid": "9fd70f31-b450-465b-aec4-39f47ec6e883"
    }
  ], 
  "weburl": "https://delicious.com"
}
```

It is my intention to assign the values coming back from the RESTapi to the matching state variable but in the corresponding "val" variables.  Can this be done with the spread operator?

Comment: Not sure why you need the mapping to `val` and `err` but with `reduce` and spread operator it should work. Do you want it like in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-sun-dbih2)? If that's OK I can create an answer and add some details to the code.

Comment: AWolf that seems like an awful lot of work when I could just assign the values directly to the state.  I was hoping that there would be a shortcut way of doing it.  I don't want you to go through the trouble.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Elcid_91, AWolf's snippet is about as concise as you can expect if you want the results to match your supplied example.

Comment: Kevin...completely understand and it is a solution to the question; however, there are just not enough fields to warrant writing the extra code.  AWolf, if you want to create an answer, I will tick my question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Its not pretty but you can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to get the properties you're interested in:

```js
const parseResponseObject = ({
  recordid,
  companyname,
  address,
  telephone,
  email,
  taxid,
  weburl,
}) => ({
  recordid,
  companyname: { val: companyname, err: '' },
  address: { val: address, err: '' },
  telephone: { val: telephone, err: '' },
  email: { val: email, err: '' },
  taxid: { val: taxid, err: '' },
  weburl: { val: weburl, err: '' },
  loading: true,
})

const response = {
  address: '9242 Kropf Court\nTulsa, OK 74133',
  balance: '1937.2400',
  companyname: 'HUB Pharmaceuticals, LLC',
  email: [
    {
      emailaddress: 'lespinha4r@salon.com',
      emailname: 'Lizbeth Espinha',
      recordid: 'ea18a1b3-860d-45ed-a6bc-b5208dcfbac7',
    },
  ],
  recordid: 'fe435915-0e5c-4165-80ca-28c69a5d1ed8',
  taxid: '132798707',
  telephone: [
    {
      phonename: 'Office',
      phonenumber: '9185499797',
      recorder: 1,
      recordid: '9fd70f31-b450-465b-aec4-39f47ec6e883',
    },
  ],
  weburl: 'https://delicious.com',
}

const result = parseResponseObject(response)

console.log(result)
```

---

Or, you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) along with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). But this will turn each property to the `{ val, err }` format and it looks like your not doing that to the `recordid` prop and dropping the `balance` prop.

```js
const parseResponseObject = response =>
  Object.entries(response).reduce((obj, [k, v]) => ({
    ...obj,
    [k]: { val: v, err: '' },
  }), {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```js
const data = {
    "address": "9242 Kropf Court\nTulsa, OK 74133",
    "balance": "1937.2400",
    "companyname": "HUB Pharmaceuticals, LLC",
    "email": [{
        "emailaddress": "lespinha4r@salon.com",
        "emailname": "Lizbeth Espinha",
        "recordid": "ea18a1b3-860d-45ed-a6bc-b5208dcfbac7"
    }],
    "recordid": "fe435915-0e5c-4165-80ca-28c69a5d1ed8",
    "taxid": "132798707",
    "telephone": [{
        "phonename": "Office",
        "phonenumber": "9185499797",
        "recorder": 1,
        "recordid": "9fd70f31-b450-465b-aec4-39f47ec6e883"
    }],
    "weburl": "https://delicious.com"
}

const state = {
    recordid: "",
    companyname: { val: "", err: "" },
    address: { val: "", err: "" },
    telephone: { val: [], err: "" },
    email: { val: [], err: "" },
    taxid: { val: "", err: "" },
    weburl: { val: "", err: "" },
    loading: true
}

const result = (d,state)=>({
    ...state,
    ...Object.entries(d).reduce((p,[k,val])=>(p[k] = ({
        val,
        err: ''
    }), p), {})
})

console.log(result(data, state))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
state = {
      recordid: "",
      companyname: {val:"",err:""},
      address: {val:"",err:""},
      telephone: {val:[],err:""},
      email: {val:[],err:""},
      taxid: {val:"",err:""},
      weburl: {val:"",err:""},
      loading: true
}
    
const response = {
  "address": "9242 Kropf Court\nTulsa, OK 74133", 
  "balance": "1937.2400", 
  "companyname": "HUB Pharmaceuticals, LLC", 
  "email": [
    {
      "emailaddress": "lespinha4r@salon.com", 
      "emailname": "Lizbeth Espinha", 
      "recordid": "ea18a1b3-860d-45ed-a6bc-b5208dcfbac7"
    }
  ], 
  "recordid": "fe435915-0e5c-4165-80ca-28c69a5d1ed8", 
  "taxid": "132798707", 
  "telephone": [
    {
      "phonename": "Office", 
      "phonenumber": "9185499797", 
      "recorder": 1, 
      "recordid": "9fd70f31-b450-465b-aec4-39f47ec6e883"
    }
  ], 
  "weburl": "https://delicious.com"
}

for(let key of Object.keys(state)) {
  if(typeof(response[key]) !== "undefined") {
    if(typeof(state[key]) === "object") {
      state[key].val = response[key];
    } else {
      state[key] = response[key];
    }
  }
}

console.log(state)
```